# The knob on rabbit ears

Tags: antenna, receiver

So I was reading some fiction about where the character bought a television and
"and the fanciest pair of rabbit ears available. The rabbit ears even had a large tuner knob built in to it that I'm sure didn't do a damn thing for reception but man did it ever make it look hi-tech."

OK now this is obviously a receive only setup with the old ntsc television standard, and I remember owning a set top antenna with a knob or two I know the first one was 300 ohm (I took that one apart), latter ones may have been 75 ohm. but I never understood what the knob was supposed to do or how it worked. the one I took apart had (if my fuzzy memory is right, this was at least 15 years ago) a hybrid mutli-throw switch where both poles were on opposite sides of the sweep arm and a bunch of induction coils. I don't remember seeing any capacitors, but I have slept since then.

So what is this supposed to do and how does it work?

Comment: I'm not sure how obsolete TV rabbit ears relate to amateur radio, and I'm not sure if the workings of something you read about in some fiction or something you barely remember can objectively be explained. Perhaps if you add some references to real products there will be more to go on.